# Convert a .PKG to .DMG

Tags: macos

We're trying to deploy an application in .pkg format in our environment to a few Macs. Unfortunately, the application installer is in a .pkg format and we are unable to deploy it in this state. Is it possible to extract to a .dmg in order to deploy? Or is there another file extension that would be better suited, besides .pkg?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I can recommend anything without more info. How are you trying to deploy software that .pkg installers won't work? What *will* work? Also, what's the software? Some installers simply place files, but others do more complex things; depending on what the .pkg does, it may be impractical to convert to any other format. Finally, I should note that a .dmg file is just a container; it doesn't define what should be done with its contents. A .dmg can contain files that need to be copied somewhere (where?), or it might contain one or more .pkgs, or ... pretty much anything.